# VPN Server configuration in Ec2 AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, openvpn, aws-cli

I am looking to setup a VPN Server in AWS EC2 instance. I do understand ec2 instances have limited bandwidth according to its instance type.

Let assume, I have a t2 medium instance on which VPN Server is configured and running but i want to implement a limit for each user to consume defined limit of bandwidth. like total bandwidth of ec2 instance is 10 Mbs and 2 users are connected to my server but they can use 2 Mbs speed each however, rest 6 Mbs will be free.

Is there any way we can do that. Does EC2 instance provide this feature to implement bandwidth division either directly on instance or by using any third party tool.

Comment: That is something you would do with the OS or VPN software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "shaper" option if you use OpenVPN as your VPN server. If you want to set speed limits by each client, you can set the option in the client config file. However note that clients can change it.

If you set the option is server config, all clients will be treated with the same value.

Read OpenVPN man page for more info:

> https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

Reference: [Openvpn Bandwidth Limit](https://serverfault.com/questions/568795/openvpn-bandwidth-limit)

Comment: @ThilianB, Can you please provide me an example of server config with having some limit on downrate and uprate for each client.