# limit bandwidth per IP Linux ubuntu openVPN

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-18.04, tc, bandwidth-control, limitations

I am a newmember in config ubuntu server and I installed an OpenVPN on a ubuntu 18.04 linux server, now I want to limit the server bandwidth with 2Mbit per IP for users that connect to the OpenVPN, and I should say I have just 1 ovpn client file and all users use this file, also I don't understand users IP, because users connect with a mobile app around the world.

I checked something before but unfortunately they didn't work for me. I installed wondershaper used `./wondershaper -a eth0 -u 2048 -d 2048` and also I used `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root tbf rate 2mbit burst 32kbit latency 200ms` but both of them affects on eth0 device and limit it to 2Mbit , I mean when a user connect to the VPN server and download something with 2Mbit speed, others lose their connection and can't use the Internet.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Serverfault. You may want to have a look at : https://serverfault.com/a/568801/146493

Comment: @OlivierDulac Hi, thanks :), I tried to do it, but unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorial in the Internet for how to do it, I mean does it need to config server and client file all in once, or just config server.conf file or ...